# Download and execute groovy code

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using `Jenkins` pipeline (`groovy` syntax).
I have multiple projects and I want to share some code with all of the projects.

Is it possible to define a function in a file on a remote server, and then download that file, import the function and execute it?

For example, `Jenkinsfile` on a project named `cicd`. From another project (say `core`), Jenkinsfile execute`sharedFunction` from the jenkinsfile project `cicd`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.  However, you can define a set of functions in groovy and load them into a jar, then 'bless' that jar (install into Jenkins) as a set of approved functions so that they can run inside Jenkins pipeline jobs.

Look for "Global Pipeline Libraries" - it's an entry in the "Configure Jenkins" page (you have to be able to manage the Jenkins, or else convince the Jenkins administrators to approve your library.)  Its description says "Sharable libraries available to any Pipeline jobs running on this system. These libraries will be trusted, meaning they run without 'sandbox' restrictions and may use @Grab."

It is relatively straightforward, but I suggest installing your own Jenkins where you have complete control and can create and play with a 'Hello, World!' function so you can see the steps involved in getting your production functions installed.  Since I didn't manage the Jenkins I needed functions for (and it had none already), doing a local walkthrough made it possible to describe to the admins exactly what was needed in my 'bless' request, and they seemed to appreciate that.

For instructions and getting set up, see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/.

Answer (score 0):

The below pipeline snippet we use to run the groovy code hosted in remote server.

```
node {
    git url : 'git@our.repo.host.com:somepath/reponame.git'
    load 'script/jenkins/createTag-pipeline.groovy'
}
```